# Styling the ActionBar background color removes title text

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the styles.xml to change the colour of my actionbar to orange (defined in the colors.xml)

But by doing so, the activity title has disappeared.

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/adgen_orange</item>
    <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: When does the title appear?

Comment: Well it should be in the Action Bar, but as I stated in my question, its no longer visible for whatever reason.

Comment: I meant to ask 'have you confirmed that the activity title appears with other colours?'

Comment: Well, it appeared without customisation. I will check with other colours.

Comment: Well, it seems to have fixed itself! I tested with white, and i could see it, changed back to orange, and it works.